# jQuery reducing code for better maintainability?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery you can do

```
$("#id1, #id2").doSomething();
```

But what if you have

```
var $id1 = $("#id1");
var $id2 = $("#id2");
```

Is there a way to easily group them together and execute doSomething()?

```
$($id1, $id2).doSomething(); //ERROR
```

Having only two elements is fine, but if I have like more than 10 elements. I would need to repeat doing...

```
$id1.doSomething();
$id2.doSomething();
....
```

Is there a easy way to group them?

Comment: That's not really what jquery is for. If you have lots of jquery objects that you need to store references to, keep them in an array and iterate over that array.

Comment: @Falmarri jQuery objects are already arrays/sets of DOM elements, why have two levels of nesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var $allIds = $id1.add($id2);
$allIds.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have proposition: maybe you can set to those elements new class. For example:

Html code:

```
<div>
    <div id="id1" class="exampleClass">...</div>
    <div id="id2" class="exampleClass">...</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(".exampleClass").doSomething();
```

This would work for all elements.

Comment: Thanks, i know this... but i just wanted to know how you could add additional dom like $.add